# SailsJS connection with Azure MS SQL Database

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, azure-sql-database, sails.js

I installed the latest version of Sails on my computer and created a new project.
I am using SailsJS as my API and want to connect to the clients' Azure MS SQL database.

I tried using the mssql npm package, even the MS SQL adaptor listed on the Sails documents site, but non of these are working.

With mssql I get the following error when running sails lift in the terminal:
` info: Starting app...

error: A hook (`orm`) failed to load!
error:
error: Error: Consistency violation: the adapter for datastore `default` does not have an `identity` property.
at validateDatastoreConfig`

Any guidance will be appreciated...

Comment: are you trying to set value for identity attribute of datastore?
As per (sailsjs)[https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/model-settings#?identity] identity is read-only attribute and automatically derived.

Comment: Getting this error:
error: A hook (`orm`) failed to load!
error: Error: Consistency violation: the adapter for datastore `default` does not have an `identity` property.
    at validateDatastoreConfig (/Users/mk/Projects/SailsJS/backend/node_modules/sails-hook-orm/lib/validate-datastore-config.js:54:13)
...
with datastores.js content as follows:
`module.exports.datastores = {
default: {
adapter: require('mssql'),
user: <user>,
password: <password>,
host: <host> // azure database
port: 1433,
database: <dB>,
authentication: {type: 'default'},
options: {encrypt: true}
}};`